# How to fix a broken Ruby config

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I use a MacOs High Sierra 10.13.6. `bundle install` does not work anymore. I had been using the bundler to run fastlane lanes for years on this machine. I recently installed other sofware and I guess I made a mistake and broke the configuration.

I have the following Gemfile:

source "https://rubygems.org"

```
gem 'fastlane', '2.120.0'
gem 'aws-sdk', '2.10.8'
gem 'awscli', '0.2.8'
gem 'rake', '12.0.0'
gem 'danger', '5.4.3'

plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fastlane', 'Pluginfile')
eval(File.read(plugins_path), binding) if File.exist?(plugins_path)
```

When I try to run `bundle install` I get the error:

> ERROR: cannot discover where libxml2 is located on your system. please make sure `pkg-config` is installed.
>
> An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.2), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2'
>   --source 'https://rubygems.org/' succeeds before bundling.

if I run:

`gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2'`

or

`gem install nokogiri -v 1.8.2 -n /usr/local/bin -- --use-system-libraries`

I get the error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
>       Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/.autotest

I have tried to change the permission of the folder and run:

```
gem install pkg-config -n /usr/local/bin -- --use-system-libraries
gem install nakogiri -v 1.8.2 -n /usr/local/bin -- --use-system-libraries
```

As suggested by one of the error messages I have also run:

`bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries`

In this case these commands succeed but the `bundle install` still fails with the same error.

Comment: Fiddling with the system Ruby on macOS is rarely a good idea. Using a version manager (as shown in your own answer below) is – once you get used to it – much easier, especially when dealing with different projects / requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).
Then in the `.zshrc` file I appended:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Then I run:

`rvm reinstall all --force`

and now it is working.